# How to define this association properly using active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, has-one

I have the following two models in an application

```
class City
end

class Suburb
end
```

a city has exactly 5 suburbs, north, east, south, west and center. I want to reference each suburb through a correspondent method so that, 
north is accessed through city.north
south is accessed through city.south

I can add a foreign key for each suburb in the `cities` table and use `belongs_to` and `has_one` to define each association. But I find it not as intuitive as it should be. This is because a Suburb belongs_to a City and the not the inverse. so the following definition is not intuitive.

```
class City
  belongs_to :north, class_name: 'Suburb'
  belongs_to :east, class_name: 'Suburb'
  belongs_to :south, class_name: 'Suburb'
  belongs_to :west, class_name: 'Suburb'
  belongs_to :center, class_name: 'Suburb'
end

class Suburb
  has_one :city
end
```

this works as expected. but when you read it, its the inverse. a Suburb belongs_to City and a City has_one :north, has_one :east, has_one :south, has_one :west and has_one :center.

I tried also to define a `has_many :suburbs` on the `city` model, and add an enum property `direction` to the suburb model than define a method, using define_method' for each direction, but I see it over engineered.

Is there a way to model this properly.

Comment: Could a suburb be, say, the 'north' of one city and the 'south' of another? If yes, you might be inching toward a 'has_and_belongs_to_many' type of realtionship.

Comment: @enkrates No, a suburb belongs to only one city.

Comment: What is the list of attributes that a suburb has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing inherently wrong with your schema, but for the sake of discussion, let me present an alternative that satisfies your modelling concerns:

Let's have `Suburb` belong to `City`, as you propose. In order to enforce the uniqueness of suburbs with respect to their city, we add a `direction` column to our `suburbs` table, along with a unique composite index that combines `city_id` and `direction`. This way a `Suburb` belongs to exactly one city, and a city cannot have more than one `Suburb` in a given `direction`.

**db/migrate/...create_suburbs.rb**

```
class CreateDeviseUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.change
    create_table(:suburbs) do |t|
      # no need for `index: true` here because of composite key below
      t.references :city, null: false
      t.text :direction, null: false

      t.index [:city_id, :direction], unique: true
    end
  end
end
```

**app/models/city.rb**

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :suburbs
end
```

Our `Suburb` model is now a little more complex. We need a validation for `direction`, and a scope for each possible value. I like to add a getter that ensures `direction` is always a symbol as well.

**app/models/suburb.rb**

```
class Suburb < ActiveRecord::Base
  DIRECTIONS = [:north, :east, :south, :west]

  belongs_to :city

  validates :city, presence: true
  validates :direction, inclusion: { in: DIRECTIONS }

  # define a scope for each direction
  DIRECTIONS.each { |d| scope d, -> { where(direction: d) } }

  # convenience getter so that we can reason about direction using symbols
  def direction
    self[:direction].try(:to_sym)
  end
end
```

Now we can access and drill down on cities suburbs using the scopes:

```
# all north suburbs
north_suburbs = Suburb.north

# northern suburbs of a city (there can only be one!)
north_suburbs = city.suburbs.north

# as a model
north_suburb = city.suburbs.north.first
```

If you really don't like the `first` bit, you can define convenience accessors:

**app/models/city.rb**

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :suburbs

  def north
    suburbs.north.first
  end

  # ...
end
```

Comment: I think this is the way to go, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you need an extra model, CitySuburb, such that both City and Suburb has_many CitySuburbs, and CitySuburb belongs to both City and Suburb.

You can place scopes on CitySuburb for north, south etc, and hence associate City with north_suburb, south_suburb etc.

Comment: that's too much, I do not have a many to many relationship here, I have a one to many relationship.